# How to use popperComponent Props while using useAutoComplete in material ui reactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change position of popper using useAutocomplete I can easily do it with autocomplete but i want to do this with useAutocomplete

Comment: please add more details about what you need to accomplish, `useAutocomplete` is used for custom components, add the code of your ui and explain what popper you want to change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the list within a popper element and use placement prop to specify the position.

Note: You have to tie up popper element with the input element in order to display it right under the textbox.

```
<Popper open={Boolean(anchorEl)} anchorEl={anchorEl} placement="right">
    {groupedOptions.length > 0 ? (
      <ul className={classes.listbox} {...getListboxProps()}>
        {groupedOptions.map((option, index) => (
          <li {...getOptionProps({ option, index })}>{option.title}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    ) : null}
  </Popper>
```

You can find the implementation here:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/useautocomplete-pmckw

***Placement prop of popper element takes in following values :
'bottom-end'
| 'bottom-start'
| 'bottom'
| 'left-end'
| 'left-start'
| 'left'
| 'right-end'
| 'right-start'
| 'right'
| 'top-end'
| 'top-start'
| 'top'***

Currently useAutocomplete and autocomplete are under material-ui lab. This is an entire implementation of auto-complete feature using react material-ui core components alone:

> https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-9enud